# Retrieving value from Mongoose Promise as a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

Having trouble pulling the data from a mongoose promise. I want to find a set of users from mongoose using an appropriate ID and passing the result along a promise chain.

The query is pulling the right data from the database. When I nest the query inside of a promise chain and then attempt to pass along the result, my console.log shows `[Function (anonymous)]`. Is there an appropriate structure for pulling the data from MongoDB using mongoose and then passing that data along a promise chain?

Promise chain:

```
addItem(guildId, items, timeCreated) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // other functionality omitted for brevity
        resolve(guildId, items, timeCreated);
    }).then((guild, item, timeCreate) => {
        findGroupUsers(guild).then((response) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                console.log(response.userId);
                resolve(response);
            });
        });
```

Mongoose query:

```
const findGroupUsers = async (guildId) => {
    const members = await EngagementTracking.find({ guildId: `${guildId}` }).exec();
    console.log(members);
    return members;
};
```

---

The verified answer successfully pulls the data from the query inside of addItem. To continue and pass the **result** of the query along chain, I did the following:

```
addItem(guildId, items, timeCreated) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//other functionality
        resolve(guildId, items, timeCreated);
    }).then((guild, items, timeCreate) => {
        return findGroupUsers(guild).then((response) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(response); });
        });
    }).then((data) =>{// other functionality //});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function add item seem a bit strange you should do this instead:

```
addItem(guildId, items, timeCreated) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // other functionality omitted for brevity
        resolve(guildId, items, timeCreated);
    }).then((guild, predict, timeCreate) => {
        return findGroupUsers(guild).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.userId);
          return response;
        });
```

you don't need to return a new promise inside a .then
also be warn that you should return your promise (you didn't return findGroupUser)

at the end you should have a addItem.then(/*do something*/) or an await

Comment: Yes, there's other functionality I want to do with the data once its been retrieved from the database. I tried returning a new promise inside of the nested .then() to force the chain to wait for the response and then send the new one. The problem (still present when I tried your answer) is that it's passing through an anonymous function to the response. This means I actually can't access the data retrieved from the query as I'm passing along the promise to do the query (I believe)

Comment: the 'await EngagementTracking.find({ guildId: `${guildId}` }).exec();' is a promise because of the .exec()

Comment: @tempnameenjoyer can you show us how are you using the function addItem please ? because I'm not suer to understand, by the way your return new promise inside a .then doesn't work like a wait more than just returning the promise because at the end ... you are returning a promise.

Comment: Added functioning code to my question. Yours was correct, just had to resolve a new promise to continue adding along the data to the addItem chain.